# sublimetext3: how to exclude one, specific folder from the project?

Tags: sublimetext3

I'd like to exclude one specific folder from the project. Let's say:
./src/test
I don't want to use

```
"folder_exclude_patterns":["test"]
```

because it excludes all folders with name "test" from the project. When I try to use folder path, my directive is ignored at all

```
"folder_exclude_patterns":["./src/test"]
"folder_exclude_patterns":[".\\src\\test"]
```

How to achieve such a selective exclusion?

Answer (score 2):

Did you try this one?

```
{
    "folders":
    [
        {
            "path": "src",
            "folder_exclude_patterns": ["src/test"]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Yes - it works for subdirectory. But I need to exclude one at top level as well. If you use simply "test" it excludes all "test"s everywhere

Comment: What do you meat under "at top level"? If you don't want to see some folder at top level, just don't add it into `folders` list.

Comment: I have project folder "my_project". And this is the only folder added to project. I'd like to exclude my_project/xyz.

Comment: so add "my_project/xyz"

Comment: hm... my_project is project root; if i exclude "my_project/xyz" doesn't it mean "my_project/my_project/xyz" ???

Comment: If you add "my_project/xyz" it would exclude "my_project/xyz", "my_project/my_project/xyz", "my_project/some_folder/my_project/xyz", and so on. But since it's very unlikely that you have such folder structure, only the first one would be excluded